# Cancel the StreamSubscription

Tags: flutter

I'm using this [keyboard](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) package to check for visibility  of my keyboard. It works fine where I wan it to. However it seems to be affecting(when I remove the package, keyboard acts as expected) my keyboard else where in the widget tree. How can I cancel the subscription that I'm listening to in  initState? I presume I need to do something in `dispose`? I'm not really sure what the plugin is doing!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      bool _keyboardState;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _keyboardState = KeyboardVisibility.isVisible;
        KeyboardVisibility.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
          setState(() {
            _keyboardState = visible;
          });
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: KeyboardDismissOnTap(
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Keyboard Visibility Example'),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Input box for keyboard test',
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(height: 60.0),
                      Text(
                        'The keyboard is: ${_keyboardState ? 'VISIBLE' : 'NOT VISIBLE'}',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `listen` method on a `Stream` you will get a `StreamSubscription` which you can use later to cancel your subscription. Here is how you can unsubscribe when widget is disposed or you pushed another widget on screen and subscribe again when other widget is popped:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _keyboardState;
  StreamSubscription keyboardOnChaneSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _keyboardState = KeyboardVisibility.isVisible;
    subscribeToKeyboardOnChange();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    keyboardOnChaneSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  void subscribeToKeyboardOnChange() {
    keyboardOnChaneSubscription =
        KeyboardVisibility.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
          setState(() {
            _keyboardState = visible;
          });
        });
  }

  void navigateToScreenA() async {
    keyboardOnChaneSubscription.cancel();
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ScreenA()));
    subscribeToKeyboardOnChange();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: KeyboardDismissOnTap(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Keyboard Visibility Example'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Input box for keyboard test',
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(height: 60.0),
                  Text(
                    'The keyboard is: ${_keyboardState ? 'VISIBLE' : 'NOT VISIBLE'}',
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () => navigateToScreenA())
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds great. But I suppose my problem is dispose isn't called. But the answer looks correct. So I'll mark it so. Any idea how/where to call cancel on the Subscription if it remains in tree.

Comment: You should focus on your main problem: dispose not being called when you don't need a widget. If you could ask another question and provide some more detailed code about how you're bringing the widget in tree and how you're trying to remove it from tree I can help better @flutter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400863/where-can-i-cancel-streamsubscription